# Setting Up EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set up EmberJS. This is my first website attempting this so please excuse my noobness. Currently nothing is outputting to the screen but the body's grey background color. I'm not sure where I went wrong in setting up my EmberJS page.
Here's the code and if you need to see it in action you can view it here http://andrewhnovak.com/newSite/index.html
HTML

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mainPage.css">


</head>

<body>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='application'>

<div class="container">
<div class="header">
 <div class='col-md-1'>
 Logo
 </div><!--end header container-->
 <div class='col-md-2 col-md-offset-1'>
 <div class='link1'>
 <a href="#">Link1</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-3'>
  <div class='link2'>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-2'>
 <div class='link3'>
<a href="#">Link3</a>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class='col-md-2'>
 <div class='searchBar'>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Box">
 </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-1'>
<div class='searchButton'>
<button class="btn btn-search" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<div class="container">
<div class='underHeader'>

</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class='whiteBox'>
<div class='newProducts'>
</div>
{{outlet}}
</div>
</div>
  </script>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
 <h1>Testing the page</h1> 
  </script>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/ember-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});
```

Comment: I looked in the JavaScript console and noticed errors that jQuery is missing. Since it looks like you’re just starting out with your Ember project, I strongly recommend you use [Ember CLI](http://ember-cli.com), which is becoming the new default for Ember applications.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. But I imported jQuery.js and it seems to be working now. Thanks! What benefit does Ember CLI hold over me doing it myself?

Comment: The globals-style Ember application, where everything hangs off a global `App` object, is falling out of favour. Ember CLI provides a default structure for your application where the source for various types lives in separate directories. It also supports an addon infrastructure that is growing quickly so you can benefit from shared solutions. Like it says in [The Road to Ember 2.0 RFC](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15): **You should begin moving your app to Ember CLI as soon as possible.** If you’re just starting out, now’s the best time!

Comment: (I submitted an answer so this question can be marked as answered hehe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like from checking the JavaScript console that you’re missing jQuery.

Comment: I installed emberjs via ember-cli, but I'm having an issue when I try and view the app in action via http://localhost:4200. It says "Run 'bower install' to install missing dependencies. I type bower install and then ember server, but the message still comes up. Any Suggestions how how to get past this issue?

Comment: Hmm, are you on Windows? What are the missing dependencies?

Comment: I got it working using Git. Thanks for the quick response though. One more question I tried to add my previous code and imported my css file but the only thing it says is Welcome to EmberJS and Testing the Page. The links and header bar aren't there and the body background color didn't change. Why is that?

Comment: Where did you put the CSS? I don’t think it does any kind of automatic inclusion of files in `app/styles/`. Did you just paste them into `app.css`?

Comment: I created a folder inside app called css. The css file is called mainPage.css. I imported it into the index.html file as you can see in the html file at the top of the page. Also none of the code in div class header is appearing.

Comment: Oh, well the Ember CLI way is to put your styles in `app/styles/app.css`. Creating another directory in `app` won’t have any effect if Ember CLI doesn’t know to look for it. [The documentation](http://www.ember-cli.com/#stylesheets) has more details on stylesheets.

Comment: Oh Ok well that fixed that, but what about the header bar not showing up? See code above to see what I'm talking about

Comment: I don’t see what you mean above. Is the template in `/app/templates/`? This has grown pretty off-topic and Stack Overflow is complaining, I suggest reading the Ember CLI documentation and opening a new question if you need to.